# Async teardown logic in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

Say I have an observable of book ids:

```js
const bookId$ = new Subject<string>();
```

In the backend there is a `LibraryService` which allows the frontend to borrow a book by calling `borrowAsync(id: string) -> Promise<Book>` and return it by calling `returnAsync(id:string) -> Promise<void>`. The rule is, 1) only one book can be borrowed at a time, and 2) every borrowed book must be returned.

Now I'd like to transform the `book_id$` to an observable of borrowed book:

```js
const book$ = bookId$.pipe( //...
```

How do I achieve this? I'm thinking `switchMap`:

```js
const book$ = bookId$.pipe(
  switchMap(bookId => {
    return new Observable<Book> (observable => {
      let currentBook: Book | undefined = undefined;
      LibraryService.borrowAsync(bookId).then(
        book => {
          currentBook = book;
          observable.next(book);
          observable.complete();
        },
        // also handles error in the production code
      );

      // teardown logic
      return () => {
        if (currentBook) {
          LibraryService.returnAsync(currentBook.id);  // !!! NOT AWAITED
        }
      };
    });
  })
);
```

It's good if a new `bookId` has been produced, the teardown logic will be executed for the previously borrowed book (if existed); but the catch here is, since the returning process is async, we'll have to `await` it to complete, in order to borrow the next book, so this piece of code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can so something like:

```js
this.book$ = this.bookId$.pipe(
      switchMap((id) => {
        return concat(
          from(this.library.returnCurrentBorrowedBookAsync()).pipe(
            ignoreElements() // because we don't want the result of that operation
          ),
          this.library.borrowAsync(id)
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

The magic lays in the [concat](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) operator: we make sure to release the current book before taking a new one from the libary.
Note [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) converts Promise to Observable.

I assume that the returnAsync is always successful.
Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-aggs1n?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I agree this can help a bit, but it's still imperfect in two ways:

1. another state object has to be involved to keep track of the "current borrowed" book;
2. it does not return the last book as `book$` is being unsubscribed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature request discussed [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/discussions/6333). It's not likely to be implemented in rxjs (or any ReactiveX implementation, if that matters) in the near future.